# Forum Subscribe - Multiple Boards

Tags: devdemon, forum, discussion

Forum subscribe is only displaying my first board, I have another board but for some reason it does not output the forums for that one.

Anyone know how i can target the second board?

Answer (score 0):

If you add `board="board_name"` it should pull from the appropriate board.